# GCM to FCM Migration: client subscription question

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

For a new Firebase project I add the SenderId to my desktop websites manifest (and do not use VAPID authentication).

On a successful pushManager.subscription() the token I get back from the pushSubscription is of the format:

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/*instance_token*
```

I expected it to be using the firebase endpoint instead:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/*instance_token*
```

I can successfully send push notifications to this token through the firebase endpoint.

My questions are:

1. Why do I get a GCM endpoint in the token for a firebase project?
2. Will this always be the case or is something going to change when GCM is discontinued?
3. Can we continue to use the legacy approach of the gcm_sender_id in the manifest (over VAPID)?